# Symfony goes down after call call_user_func_array() in __call() method

Tags: php, symfony, callback, magic-methods

I have two simple classes

`Parent`

```
class Parent {
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $args);
    }
}
```

and `Child`

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private function test()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When I execute `Child` object `$child->test()` my Symfony server (runned by `php bin/console server:run`) goes down. Only message is `[ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `test()` is private and can't be executed from the `Parent` scope. Make the method `protected`.